# MacBook Pro 13 inch mid 2012 black screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I have MacBook Pro 13 inch mid 2012 model..

Earlier MBP is running with macOS mojave  ... later I upgraded with latest version “catalina”

I found strange after upgrading macOS...few flickerings are started on the screen and Later vertical 8 cm width white patch came on the screen...

Presently total screen black and no display...now I am using MBP with second display to tv screen.

Is macOS can disturb screen display..??

Please help me..

Comment: Does it show the same problem if you boot to Recovery Mode? (Hold Command R at boot.) My first guess is that the graphics hardware is failing.

Comment: I did so.. no change in the blank screen.. any how thank you for your reply...

Comment: The same behaviour on two separate boot volumes would definitely suggest a hardware failure.